# Pin a zero-length array with the fixed keyword

Tags: c#, unsafe

I've got some `unsafe` C# code that cannot be changed and that exposes methods like this:

```
static unsafe void Foo(
    byte* a, int aLength,
    byte* b, int bLength,
    byte* c, int cLength,
    byte* d, int dLength,
    byte* e, int eLength);
```

I'm calling these methods like this:

```
static void Bar(
    byte[] a, int aOffset, int aLength,
    byte[] b, int bOffset, int bLength,
    byte[] c, int cOffset, int cLength,
    byte[] d, int dOffset, int dLength,
    byte[] e, int eOffset, int eLength)
{
    fixed (byte* a_ = &a[aOffset])
    fixed (byte* b_ = &b[bOffset])
    fixed (byte* c_ = &c[cOffset])
    fixed (byte* d_ = &d[dOffset])
    fixed (byte* e_ = &e[eOffset])
    {
        Foo(a_, aLength,
            b_, bLength,
            c_, cLength,
            d_, dLength,
            e_, eLength);
    }
}
```

(Argument validation omitted for brevity.)

This works well unless one of the byte arrays has a length of zero. In this case I get an Index­Out­Of­Range­Exception.

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

How can I prevent the exception, preferably without writing lots of boilerplate code and without switching from `fixed` to something else?

The unsafe methods do not read from or write to arguments where the length is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access any elements in an array that is empty, so replace any of the arrays that are empty with a dummy array that contains an element that you can access:

```
if (aLength == 0) a = new int[1];
if (bLength == 0) b = new int[1];
if (cLength == 0) c = new int[1];
if (dLength == 0) d = new int[1];
if (eLength == 0) e = new int[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is

```
static void Bar( ... )
{
  byte[] dummy = new byte[1];
  fixed (byte* a_ = a.Lenght>0 ? &a[aOffset] : &dummy[0])
  ...
}
```

too clunky?

**Edit:**

Leaving the above in place only for historic reasons, `?` operator won't work.

So you need to do without the `fixed` keyword and do something like

```
public unsafe struct UnsafePointerStruct
{
    public GCHandle gch;
    public byte* addr;
}

static unsafe UnsafePointerStruct GetUnsafePointer(Array a, int ai)
{
    UnsafePointerStruct ups=new UnsafePointerStruct();
    ups.gch=GCHandle.Alloc(a,GCHandleType.Pinned);
    if (a.Length<=ai) ups.addr=(byte*)IntPtr.Zero;
    ups.addr=(byte*)Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(a,ai);
    return ups;
}

static unsafe void Bar(
    byte[] a, int aOffset, int aLength,
    byte[] b, int bOffset, int bLength,
    byte[] c, int cOffset, int cLength,
    byte[] d, int dOffset, int dLength,
    byte[] e, int eOffset, int eLength)
{
    UnsafePointerStruct upsa=GetUnsafePointer(a,aOffset);
    UnsafePointerStruct upsb=GetUnsafePointer(b,bOffset);
    UnsafePointerStruct upsc=GetUnsafePointer(c,cOffset);
    UnsafePointerStruct upsd=GetUnsafePointer(d,dOffset);
    UnsafePointerStruct upse=GetUnsafePointer(e,eOffset);

    Foo(upsa.addr, aLength,
        upsb.addr, bLength,
        upsc.addr, cLength,
        upsd.addr, dLength,
        upse.addr, eLength);

    upsa.gch.Free();
    upsb.gch.Free();
    upsc.gch.Free();
    upsd.gch.Free();
    upse.gch.Free();
}
```

Comment: Is there any problem with sharing the dummy across method calls, e.g. in multi-threading scenarios?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, but it would be good defensive practice to move it outside the method and pin it with a GC handle on static constructor.

Comment: Hm.. I always thought that objects should be pinned for as short as possible.

Comment: Long duration of pinning objects is very much mitigated, if the objects in question are static AND are allocated early (i.e.: They are close to the start of the object heap)

Comment: `?` not working: Seems like a hurdle to easiness, gimme a minute

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't read from or write to to arrays with length zero, you could change

```
fixed (byte* a_ = &a[aOffset])
fixed (byte* b_ = &b[bOffset])
fixed (byte* c_ = &c[cOffset])
fixed (byte* d_ = &d[dOffset])
fixed (byte* e_ = &e[eOffset])
```

to

```
fixed (byte* a_ = (a.Length == 0 ? (byte*)IntPtr.Zero : &a[aOffset]))
fixed (byte* b_ = (b.Length == 0 ? (byte*)IntPtr.Zero : &b[aOffset]))
fixed (byte* c_ = (c.Length == 0 ? (byte*)IntPtr.Zero : &c[aOffset]))
fixed (byte* d_ = (d.Length == 0 ? (byte*)IntPtr.Zero : &d[aOffset]))
fixed (byte* e_ = (e.Length == 0 ? (byte*)IntPtr.Zero : &e[aOffset]))
```

however if you do this and then try to read or write to one of the empty arrays, you'll get a nullpointer exception.

Comment: Compiler error "The right hand side of a fixed statement assignment may not be a cast expression"

Comment: Yeah it looks like c# doesn't like the ? inside the fixed initializer

Comment: Then I would go with Guffa's dummy array suggestion.